# Cannot get value for Bluetooth Peripheral Characteristic (but found in Wireshark)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, wireshark, uuid

MY GOAL: to extract the value `08660M3058` from a characteristic in my BLE device through my iOS (swift project) when device is connected or paired

CURRENT PROGRESS: Through Wireshark I was able to find that the Service UUID and Characteristic UUID were as follows (see image below)...

Service UUID = `D2F2BF0D-D165-445C-B0E1-2D6B642EC57B`
Characteristic UUID = `D2F2B8D0-D165-445C-B0E1-2D6B642EC57B`

[image]

CURRENT ISSUE: When attempting to access value via iOS app, the value for the desired characteristic is nil.

AN IDEA: Using line 6856 and 6857, it seems like I may need to write to the bluetooth device first before accessing my desired value (See image below for both write values made to the BLE device just before accesing desired value).Despite writing these values before checking in my app, the value I was still looking for was nil.

[image]
[image]

CALL FOR HELP: If you have any idea how I could access the value `08660M3058`, any help would be gladly accepted! :)

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your code?

Comment: "When attempting to access value via iOS app, the value for the desired characteristic is nil." And where is that code exactly? Can you try with LightBlue.app to check if you are able to read tha value?

Answer (score 0):

You should search for your device using the Service UUID and connect to it. When you connected successfully to the device retrieve the characteristics available. Then get the value wanted from the Characteristic UUID. There are multiple tutorials available about how to connect and retrieve data from a BLE device.